# Attaching events to window.onload

Tags: javascript, performance

I would like attach a function to window.onload so that it executes after everything is load. I have tried to do:

```
window.addEventListener('load', myFunction ,false);
window.onload = myFunction;
window.attachEvent('onload', myFunction);  (this way does not work on Chrome)
```

What happens to me is that this function, looking at the Chrome's console (Network tab) is executed before `window.onload` (before the red line). I know this, because `myFunction` tries to load a remote javascript file and this file is loaded before red line.

I have also tried something more simple:

```
$(function() {
  console.log("1111111");
});
window.onload=console.log("222222);
```

The output of that is:
`22222222222
11111111111`

Why ??? The first part should execute after DomContentLoaded and the second one after window.load  isnt it? So why is this happening?

Comment: You're calling `console.log("222222");` immediately, so of course it will run before the DOMContentLoaded event is fired. Wrap it in an anonymous function and it'll work as you expect.

Comment: you mean something like:
window.onload=function(){console.log("ssssss")}();  I have tried it, and same problem, first it outputs  22222 and then 111111

Comment: No, that still has *exactly* the same problem. You're calling the anonymous function immediately. Get rid of those `()`s at the end.

Answer (score -1):

```
// This way does not work in Chrome
```

That's because you're using `onload` instead of `load`.

Comment: Aren't you worried about `attachEvent()` instead for `addEventListener()`? Actually, this is the way to add event listeners to oldIEs.

Comment: As I understand it, author tried this approaches separately, that's why this isn't the issue.